# Merging sorted lists - C#

Tags: c#

Write a function that merges two sorted lists into a new sorted list. [1,4,6],[2,3,5] → [1,2,3,4,5,6]. You can do this quicker than concatenating them followed by a sort.

It`s something wrong with my code. It gives 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 in the result

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int [] ar1 = { 1, 4, 6};
        int [] ar2 = { 2, 3, 5};

        int[] result = Func(ar1, ar2);
        for( int n=0; n<result.Length; n++)
        Console.Write(result[n]+ ", ");

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    static int[] Func(int[] array1, int [] array2)
    {
        int[] result = new int [array1.Length + array2.Length];

        int first =0; int second = 0; int current = 0;
        while( current<result.Length) 
        {
            if ( array1[first]>array2[second]) // first is higher
            {
                result[current] = array2[second];
                if (second < array2.Length - 1) second++;
            }
            else if (array1[first] < array2[second]) // second is higher
            {
                result[current] = array1[first];
                if (first < array1.Length - 1) first++;
            }
            current++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Use the debugger. Step through the code line by line and see where you're going wrong.

Comment: In addtion to what Mike said; if you don't know how to use a debugger, spend a little time here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger

Comment: you are not (correctly) handling the condition where you have reached the end of one list, but not the other.

Comment: There's no question here. This isn't a service for finding your bugs. If you need advice on how to find bugs, start with https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to check if you are at the end of your array. If you are, you want to put the largest number at the last index:

```
static int[] Func(int[] array1, int [] array2)
{
    int[] result = new int [array1.Length + array2.Length];

    int first =0; 
    int second = 0; 
    int current = 0;

    while (current < result.Length) 
    {
        if (array1[first] > array2[second])
        {
            if (current != result.Length - 1)
            {
                result[current] = array2[second];
            }
            else
            {
                 result[current] = array1[first];
            }

            if (second < array2.Length - 1) second++;
        }
        else if (array1[first] < array2[second])
        {
            result[current] = array1[first];
            if (first < array1.Length - 1) first++;
        }
        current++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You could also implement it in this way:

```
static int[] Func(int[] array1, int[] array2)
{
    int[] result = new int[array1.Length + array2.Length];

    Array.Copy(array1, result, array1.Length);
    Array.Copy(array2, 0, result, array1.Length, array2.Length);

    Array.Sort(result);

    return result;
}
```